how to find out the duplicate fields define in both java base class and subclass
I have a java base class defined like this:
@Data
public class BaseClass {
      private Long id;
      ......
}

the subclass look like this:
@Data
public class SubClass extends BaseClass {
      private Long id;
      ......
}

right now the class has many fields that both defined in base class and sub class. There is no tips when the fields exists in both class. And I have many subclass extends the base class. is there any reliable way to found out the duplicate defined fields? or I have to diff the define one by one? Now I am using the Intellij Idea and did not found a way to do this.

Why do you want that? How you end up in this situation? I doubt you find existing tools for that, because it is perfectly legal code. You may look into ArchUnit and create your own test that find such fields.

it works fine with multiple define in base class and sub class, i just want to remove the fields from sub class that could make the class more clean. Now there has too many fields both in base and sub class. if there contains tips to help me remove the duplicate define that will be better.

I'll post this as a comment rather than as an answer, as it might help somebody in a similar situation. This solution addresses only hiding cases, therefore it does not answer the question, as there is no hiding when the fields of a subclass match the name of private fields in the base class. To turn on warnings for hiding fields In IntelliJ IDEA, enable the inspection Subclass field hides superclass field. To do that, go to File > Settings > Editor > Inspections > Java > Visibility > Subclass field hides superclass field

You can use reflection to find them, I leave you a very very basic example:
void findDuplicateField( Object obj ) {
    Field campos[] = obj.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
    Field camposPadre[] = obj.getClass().getSuperclass().getDeclaredFields();
    for( Field m : campos ) {
        for( Field mP : camposPadre ) {   //  Method m : metodos,
            if( m.getName().equals( mP.getName() ) ) {
                try {
                    System.out.println( "yeahhh!!! !!!" );
                    System.out.println( "Duplicate -> " + mP.getName() );
                }
                catch( IllegalArgumentException e ) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

Of course, you have to add a folder and file explorer, save the items found, etc...
